# Is the sentence "Still be worried about..." correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Still be worried about the score?"

Is this sentence correct in written English or Oral English? I want to know whether we can start the sentence with "still".

Answer (score 2):

Formally, it is correct to say, "*Are you* still worried about the score?"

Informally, "Still" *can* be used at the start of the sentence, however, it is common to start with "Still" *without* using "be".

For example:

> [Hey Amanda.] Still worried about the score?

Here, "be" isn't needed. Compare with, "[Are you] still worried about the score?"

Using "be" only sounds right if there's a modal verb and a [pro]noun supporting "be".

For example:

> [Should you] still [be] worried about the score?

Comment: It should be pointed out that this is an informal usage. The 'correct' version would be _Are you still worried...?_

Comment: @KateBunting: Thanks, I've edited my answer.